DAX needing to operate on two part complex need
I am attempting a DAX formula that will consider filter context for fields report_month and sales_rep when calculating the sum of a field. There are two main logic points at play here.

The values should only sum when certain people are selected and not count those that are also selected from the exclusion list. However, if those from the exclusion list are selected either independently or together and only those from the exclusion list - they are still summed. The sum of those that are not in the exclusion list only override that of the non exclusion list when they are also selected with members of the non exclusion list.

When a report month is selected in the filter pane - filter context is ignored. So that if I have a column chart with the report month in the x-axis and the measure in the y-axis - if I select a specific report month from the filter pane, I will still see say - 6 months of data in the chart.


The issue with this code - 1 and 2 work under all conditions except when an exclusion person is selected AND a report month is selected. In that case - the results are not static which should display the last 6 months of data.
Is this even possible with DAX to have it consider aggregating certain people over others based on who is selected in the people filter in the filter pane + keep the measure static regardless of what is selected for the report month in the filter pane?
This logic works independently. But I cannot combine them. I understand another route is to use visual slicers and use 'edit interactions' to ignore filtering. I would rather try it with a DAX formula thought because my audience is already used to using the filter pane + I do not have a ton of real-estate to add slicers. Thank you in advance.
Code:
m_static_spiff = 
VAR MaxDate2024 =
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('report_month_filter'[report_month]),
        ALL('report_month_filter'),  // Removes all filters from this table
        YEAR('report_month_filter'[report_month]) = 2024
    )
VAR StartDate = EDATE(MaxDate2024, -5)

VAR ExcludedReps = {
    "person 1", "person 2", "person 3", "person 4"
}
VAR IsIndividualRep = HASONEVALUE(all_agg_com[sales_rep])
-- If the current context has one sales rep, get that rep's name, otherwise return BLANK
VAR CurrentRep = IF(IsIndividualRep, VALUES(all_agg_com[sales_rep]), BLANK())

VAR IsExcludedRep = IsIndividualRep && CurrentRep IN ExcludedReps

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    IF(
        NOT IsIndividualRep,
        SUMX(
            FILTER(
                all_agg_com,
                NOT all_agg_com[sales_rep] IN ExcludedReps
            ),
            all_agg_com[spiff]
        ),
        IF(
            IsExcludedRep,
            CALCULATE(SUM(all_agg_com[spiff]), ALL(all_agg_com[sales_rep])),
            SUM(all_agg_com[spiff])
        )
    ),
    FILTER(
        ALL('all_agg_com'[report_month]),  // Ignore any 'report_month' slicers or filters
        'all_agg_com'[report_month] >= StartDate &&
        'all_agg_com'[report_month] <= MaxDate2024
    )
)

